# When I define og:type restaurant facebook linter shows that it is of og:type=website anyway?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a [web page](http://demo.outsourceproject.co.uk/) that belongs to the restaurant, so I tag it with og:type restaurant.
[Facebook linter reports it](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=demo.outsourceproject.co.uk/categories/13-starters) as og:type=website though.
Any idea why is that?

Cheers,

Michal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `restaurant` is deprecated, see the documentation at http://ogp.me/ for the types of objects you can define.